# Java - Which data type for physical calculations?

Tags: java, math, types, physics

I'm trying to create a physical calculation program in Java. Therefore I used some formulas, but they always returned a wrong value. I split them and and found: (I used `long` so far.)

```
8 * 830584000 = -1945262592
```

which is obviously wrong. There are fractions and very high numbers in the formulas, such as 6.095E23 and 4.218E-10 for example.

So what datatype would fit best to get a correct result?

Comment: maybe bigDecimal?

Comment: Your question doesn't really provide enough information. In addition to `double` and `BigDecimal` also have a look at `long` and `BigInteger`.

Comment: besides the lack of information, when I do that multiplication in Java (using long), I get the result: 6644672000.

Comment: Your multiplication example fits "long". Looks like you're still using ints? For Rationals, check "Spire" or any other "Numerical Data Types" library.

Comment: Your constants are `int` literals, not `long`, so the calculation is overflowing. (It doesn't matter if you later assign it to a `long` variable; the damage is done.) If you try `8L * 830584000L`, you'll get the correct output: 6644672000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason not to, `double` is the best type for physical calculations. It was good enough for the wormhole modelling in the film Interstellar so, dare I say it, is probably good enough for you. Note well though that, as a rough guide, it only gives you only 15 decimal significant figures of precision.

But you need to help the Java compiler:

Write `8.0 * 830584000` for that expression to be evaluated in `double` precision. `8.0` is a `double` literal and causes the other arguments to be *promoted* to a similar type.

Currently you are using *integer* arithmetic, and are observing *wrap-around* effects.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Kinaeh: Do set aside a few weeks though to understand what a `double` is: start with the link?

Comment: `BigDecimal` is still the much better choice.

Comment: I tried to use double before, but also got wrong results, but the 'X.0' thing worked fine.

Comment: @Kinaeh doing it in long works perfectly too, if you do it correctly.

Comment: @daniu: For physical calculations (well, every calculation I've come across) it absolutely isn't.

Comment: Please keep in mind that floating point data types such as `float` and `double` have some *accuracy issues* with the fraction part beyond the size restriction. (e.g. 0.1 is an endless fraction in binary representation)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: Also keep in mind that many numbers (e.g. 1/3, PI, G, speed of light in a vacuum, Planck's constant) cannot be represented as a decimal either.

Comment: @Stultuske yes, you are right. I used a int value to calculate a long, there must have be something wrong. (long x = 8 * int) seems not to give a long. My apologies.

Comment: @Kinaeh: Indeed, 8 * int is an int type. It doesn't matter that you assign it to to a long: conceptually that happens afterwards.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yay, I learned some things today, thank you. This calculation thing is new to me as my last physical calculations were years ago back in school. Great that you are here to help.

Comment: @Kinaeh: Forgive me but I can't resist. IMHO C++ is **by far** the superior language for physical calculations, followed by Fortran. If your front end needs to be Java, I'd give serious thought to doing the presentation in Java, and the calculations in C++ (or even C), using a JNI to link the two.

Comment: @Bathsheba Why? I see no general reason why C++ would be better than this, if anything it depends on the context i.e. where the program is to run.

Answer (score 2):

If you need perfect accuracy for large decimal numbers, BigDecimal is the way to go, though it will be at the cost of performance. If you know you numbers are not that large, you can use long instead which should be faster, but has a much more limited range and will require you to convert from and to decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As physics calculations involves a lot of floating point operations, float data type can be a good option in such calculations. I Hope it will help. :)